# Dragging a circle on a canvas using mousedown

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, automatic-ref-counting, draw

Right now, I have 2 circles and a line in between. I want to be able to drag one of the circles with the line still attached and it will stay connected to the circle as I move it. 
The node1 and node2 are the circle dimensions. The line/muscle is connected to node1 and node2's x and y position.

```html
function draw() {
    //draw in the container
    c.fillStyle = "#000000";
    c.fillRect(container.y, container.x, container.width, container.height);

    //draw first node
    c.arc(node1.x, node1.y, node1.r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    c.fillStyle = node1.color;
    c.fill();

    //draw second node
    c.arc(node2.x, node2.y, node2.r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    c.strokeStyle = node2.color;
    c.fillStyle = node2.color;
    c.fill();

    //draw muscle
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(muscle.node1x, muscle.node1y);
    c.lineTo(muscle.node2x, muscle.node2y);
    c.strokeStyle = muscle.color;
    c.lineWidth = muscle.width;
    c.stroke();
}
```

How the project looks so far 
[image]

Comment: Stack overflow should be used to answer issues your having or specific questions about implementations you need clarification on. Not to have code written for you. Please provide code that you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is based on your `draw` function and implements the drag function.

```js
function draw(container, c, node1, node2, muscle) {
  //draw in the container
  c.fillStyle = "#000000";
  c.fillRect(container.y, container.x, container.width, container.height);

  //draw first node
  c.arc(node1.x, node1.y, node1.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  c.fillStyle = node1.color;
  c.closePath();
  c.fill();

  //draw second node
  c.arc(node2.x, node2.y, node2.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  c.strokeStyle = node2.color;
  c.fillStyle = node2.color;
  c.closePath();
  c.fill();

  //draw muscle
  c.beginPath();
  c.moveTo(muscle.node1x, muscle.node1y);
  c.lineTo(muscle.node2x, muscle.node2y);
  c.strokeStyle = muscle.color;
  c.lineWidth = muscle.width;
  c.closePath();
  c.stroke();
}

function Node(x, y, r, color) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.r = r || 20;
  this.color = color || "#ff0";
}

function Muscle(node1, node2, width, color) {
  this.node1 = node1;
  this.node2 = node2;
  this.width = width || 5;
  this.color = color || "#f00";
  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    node1x: {
      "get": () => this.node1.x,
      "set": x => { this.node1.x = x }
    },
    node1y: {
      "get": () => this.node1.y,
      "set": y => { this.node1.y = y }
    },
    node2x: {
      "get": () => this.node2.x,
      "set": x => { this.node2.x = x }
    },
    node2y: {
      "get": () => this.node2.y,
      "set": y => { this.node2.y = y }
    }
  })
}


function handleMouseDrag(canvas, nodes) {
  var isDrag = false;
  var offset = { x: 0, y: 0, x0: 0, y0: 0 };
  var dragNode = undefined;
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
    var x = e.offsetX, y = e.offsetY;
    for (var i in nodes) {
      if (Math.pow(x - nodes[i].x, 2) + Math.pow(y - nodes[i].y, 2) < Math.pow(nodes[i].r, 2)) {
        isDrag = true;
        dragNode = nodes[i];
        offset = { x: dragNode.x, y: dragNode.y, x0: x, y0: y };
        return;
      }
    }
  });
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    if (isDrag) {
      dragNode.x = e.offsetX - offset.x0 + offset.x;
      dragNode.y = e.offsetY - offset.y0 + offset.y;
    }
  });
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
    isDrag = false;
  });
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseleave", function (e) {
    isDrag = false;
  });
}

function main() {
  var node1 = new Node(40, 40);
  var node2 = new Node(120, 120);
  var muscle = new Muscle(node1, node2);

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var container = { x: 0, y: 0, get width() { return canvas.width }, get height() { return canvas.height } }
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  handleMouseDrag(canvas, [node1, node2]);

  function updateFrame() {
    ctx.save();
    draw(container, ctx, node1, node2, muscle);
    ctx.restore();
    requestAnimationFrame(updateFrame)
  };
  updateFrame();
}

main();
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="canvas"></canvas>
```